# Clicking too fast with slide gallery (jquery)

Tags: jquery, queue, slideshow

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('span#pijlr').click(function(e) {
    var slide = 500;
    var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left');
    var urechts = "-1000px";
    if(variable > urechts) {
    $('#gallcont').animate({'left': '-=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear');
    }
});

$('span#pijll').click(function(e) { 
    var slide = 500;
    var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left');
    var ulinks = "0px";
    if(variable < ulinks) {
    $('#gallcont').animate({'left': '+=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear');
    }   
}); 




});
```

This code i wrote for a simple slide gallery i made. All works fine except when i fast click the arrow buttons. It will go beyond the values i set up (urechts and ulinks).

I tried putting 'stop()' before the .animate, but it didn't help. Hope you guys can give me some advise on how to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting a `bool` in your click function to determine if it is already in transition mode.

```
var inClick = false;

$(document).ready(function(e) { 

$('span#pijlr').click(function(e) { 
    if(inClick) return;

    inClick = true;

    var slide = 500; 
    var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left'); 
    var urechts = "-1000px"; 
    if(variable > urechts) { 
    $('#gallcont').animate({'left': '-=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear', function() { inClick = false; }); 
    } 
    else inClick = false;
}); 

$('span#pijll').click(function(e) {  
    if(inClick) return;

    inClick = true;

    var slide = 500; 
    var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left'); 
    var ulinks = "0px"; 
    if(variable < ulinks) { 
    $('#gallcont').animate({'left': '+=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear', function() { inClick = false; }); 
    }    
    else inClick = false;
});  




});
```

That way your user must wait for the transition to complete to click again.

Comment: no prob :)  eZakto's solution also works great.  +1s are always very nice!

Comment: Tried but my reputation is too low:)

Answer (score 9):

What about adding some conditional, like this:

```
$('span#pijlr').click(function(e) {
    if (!$('#gallcont').is(':animated')) {
        var slide = 500;
        var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left');
        var urechts = "-1000px";
        if(variable > urechts) {
        $('#gallcont').animate({'left': '-=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear');
        }
    }
});
```

Something like that will nullify the event while the slide is animating..

Comment: Tried but my reputation is too low:)

Answer (score 2):

try using `stop(true,true)`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('span#pijlr').click(function(e) {
    var slide = 500;
    var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left');
    var urechts = "-1000px";
    if(variable > urechts) {
    $('#gallcont').stop(true,true).animate({'left': '-=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear');
    }
});

$('span#pijll').click(function(e) { 
    var slide = 500;
    var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left');
    var ulinks = "0px";
    if(variable < ulinks) {
    $('#gallcont').stop(true,true).animate({'left': '+=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear');
    }   
}); 

});
```